# Python subprocess.Popen not working for jar file

Tags: python, java, jar, subprocess

I'm on a Windows 10 machine, using a third party jar file, ccmcl.jar, from https://github.com/usnistgov/combinatorial-testing-tools/tree/master/CCM%20Command%20Line%20Tool. I have a python script that executes:

```
p1 = subprocess.Popen(['timeout', '30', 'java', '-jar', 'ccmcl.jar', '-A', 'my_text_file.txt', '-I', 'my_csv_file.csv', '-T', '3'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p1.wait()
idc_acc_array_content, err = p1.communicate()
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Invalid syntax. Default option is not allowed more than '1' time(s).
Type "TIMEOUT /?" for usage.
```

This results in `idc_acc_array = b''`. The usage is correct for that jar file and all files referenced are in the current working directory. If I remove the "timeout" portion of the subprocess line I have:

```
p1 = subprocess.Popen(['java', '-jar', 'ccmcl.jar', '-A', 'my_text_file.txt', '-I', 'my_csv_file.csv', '-T', '3'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p1.wait()
idc_acc_array_content, err = p1.communicate()
```

Again, I get that `idc_acc_array_content = b''`, and the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jfree/data/xy/XYDataset
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:56)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jfree.data.xy.XYDataset
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:476)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
        ... 3 more
```

Am I incorrect in thinking this jar file should be usable "out of the box"? Note that this is what I have in terms of my Java version:

```
$ java -version
openjdk version "11.0.15" 2022-04-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-11.0.15+10 (build 11.0.15+10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-11.0.15+10 (build 11.0.15+10, mixed mode)
```

Comment: I assume you've tried running the same commands you are trying to run through python on the command line and they work?

Comment: @saquintes - Does not work on the command line either.

Comment: Gotcha.  So no really an issue with Python or subprocess, but a problem with your jar file?